# Multilingual with HTML CSS and Javascript | What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, multilingual

I want to make the simple page available in only two languages. German and English. But it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the HTML code.

```
<p>
        <a href="#eng" data-reload>English</a>
        <a href="#de" data-reload>Deutsch</a>
      </p>
      <div>
         <h1 class="title-1">Yannick</h1>
      </div>
        <details open class="title-1">
          <summary style="outline: none;" class="hi">About Me</summary>
        </details>
```

And here is the JavaScript code.

```
var dataReload = document.querySelectorAll("[data-reload]");

  var language = {
    eng: {
      welcome: "About me"
    },
    de: {
      welcome: "Ãœber mich"
    }
  };

  // define language via window hash
  if (window.location.hash) {
    if (window.location.hash === "#de") {
      hi.textContent = language.de.welcome;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= dataReload.length; i++) {
    dataReload[i].onclick = function() {
      location.reload(true);
    }
  }
```

I am getting this error (Console):

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined
    at lang.js:20
(anonymous) @ lang.js:20
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please let us find a solution together.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= dataReload.length;` typo, you're off by 1

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: `arr[arr.length]` will be `undefined` if `arr` is array-like, because arrays are zero-indexed